# Dumping a file using XSLT to get source XML

Tags: xml, xslt, dump

Apologies if something like this has been asked already, or if it's a dumb question... I have searched for several solutions, but none so far work for me.

My issue is this: for my first task at my new job, I'm being asked to use XSLT to create a document (WordML) generated by an application. The problem is, I've never used XSLT before and I cannot see the XML document generated by the application. Checking the application, I have no way of just generating the xml file before transformation. I have questions out to the "experts," but I'm still waiting for a response.

My question is this: is it possible to generate a dump of the xml file using xslt. All I want is to see the raw data so that I can use it to identify xpaths and attributes to be used by the transform. So far, everything I've found on the Internet (here and elsewhere) does not seem to be doing what I need.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use an identity transform.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) which will copy your source tree to the result tree.

Here is a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that contains an identity transform template. If you use any XML file as the input, it will output an equivalent* file as output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(* equivalent in regard to the XPath data model - entities and CDATA sections, for example, will be converted into text nodes)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I've found that example before and it doesn't work for me. :( When I test it with a sample file used by the application, I get a blank document. And when I test it with a generic xml file, I get data dumped but no tags. Like I said, all I want is to be able to see all the navigation paths and data so I can understand how to properly manipulate the file.

Comment: I guess I should add: I'm using XML Notepad by Microsoft... could that simply be hiding the tags for whatever reason?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Which transformer are you using? How are you processing the XML source?

Comment: As I noted, above, I'm using XML Notepad. It has a transform button. No errors, either a blank document or values with no tags. It may be something owing to my own inexperience with this stuff. I guess I'm gonna have to keep at it until I get a clue. Thanks for the help.